# PHP dynamically changing div issue

Tags: php

I have encountered a small issue, and I'm not sure what's the best way to solve this.
Using this code below I'm getting 5 items per `<div>` in 1st loop, but starting from the 2nd - 4 items per `<div>`.

```
<?php   $count = 1; 
        while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            if($count === 1) {
                echo "<div id='".$data['title']."' class='images-container'>";
            }
                echo "<div id='img_div'>"; 
                    echo "<img src='uploads/" . $data['filename']."'>";
                    echo "<p class='img_title' id='".$data['title']."'>" .$data['title']. "</p>";
                    echo "<p id='img_desc'>" .$data['photo_description']. "</p>";
                    echo "<p>" .$data['price']. "</p>";
                echo "</div>";
            if($count % 5 === 0) {
                echo "</div>";
                $count = 1;
                echo "<div class='images-container'>";
            }
            $count++;
        }
?>
```

If I wouldn't need an `id` for `"<div id='".$data['title']."' class='images-container'>";` I would know how to solve this, but since I need to have a specific`id`, I'm not really sure how.

Comment: _Side note:_ The HTML you're generating will be invalid since you'll end up with multiple elements with the same id's: `img_div`, `img_desc` and with the id of `$data['title']`. Id's _must_ be unique withing a document.

Comment: The issue is that when you reset the `$count` variable, you'll still run `$count++` after, so it will end up as `2` when you start the new iteration. In your `if($count % 5 === 0) { ... }` block, replace the `echo "<div class='images-container'>";` with `continue;` and see if that works better.

Comment: I forgot to change ```id``` to ```class```, thanks for the reminder. Also, the continue works exactly like I wanted, thanks! 
Could you explain how does ```continue``` work in this instance (if you can)? Never really used it before that much.